# Santoku (libimobiledevice)

Tags: libimobiledevice

usbmux_get_device_list: error opening socket!
ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!

pleasee helppp. (not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have little knowledge of the problem or the solution, my iPhone doesn't boot up correctly and I run Santoku and I am trying to find a way to extraction iOS)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have usbmuxd installed, usbmuxd is not running, or if you're running inside a VM, you did not connect your device to your VM properly.

Did you follow the steps in this article: https://santoku-linux.com/howto/mobile-forensics/howto-create-a-logical-backup-of-an-ios-device-using-libimobiledevice-on-santoku-linux/ ?

That said, if you're planning to use libimobiledevice, why not use a regular Linux distro?